# (py)cairo - fill

Tags: python, cairo, pycairo

is there a way to fill everything outside of a closed path (polygon)?

Background: I'd like to render some maps with coastlines - so sometimes I need to fill the sea with blue color, so I thought it would be the easiest and in my situation the most efficient to fill everything outside of this coastline polygon with blue color.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This isn't an answer, but if you want to render maps with Python you could do worse than checking out the combination of [shapely](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely) and [descartes](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/descartes).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a rectangle covering the whole drawing area to your coastline path and set the fill rule to `cairo.FILL_RULE_EVEN_ODD`.  Calling `fill()` after this fills the area outside your original path.  (If you choose the correct orientation for your rectangle you can skip setting the fill rule.)

Comment: Tried this, doesn't seem to work on my hex-polygon, so switched to a Rectangle, still didn't work. Reading the docs, don't really see how it would, either - a ray from an interior point would have an odd number of intersections. [Fill Rule](https://pycairo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/enums.html#cairo.FillRule)

Comment: Actually, reading [this article](https://www.pythoninformer.com/python-libraries/pycairo/drawing-shapes/), I re-interpreted your answer. The article says it's a "shape within a shape" that gets un-filled, and I think that's what you mean by "covering the whole drawing area".

Answer (score 0):

Draw a big blue rectangle over the entire cairo surface and then draw your coastline on top of that?

Answer (score 0):

While you *could* create a closed path the size of the surface and then fill it with a solidpattern (the fill rule won't matter for a simple rectangle), it would be easier to just use the context paint() method which will fill the current clip region (that is initially set to the entire surface). It's important to do this before drawing the map/coastline boundaries and filling them so they will be on top of the background.

Comment: In my answer, the fill rule *does* matter.  I added a word to make it clearer.

Comment: @Sven Marnach: I never said it didn't matter in your answer which would fill the area around what has already been drawn assuming that the coastline path and the surrounding path are both active when fill() as called and their paths are counter to each other.